# Spring + Hibernate : java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

After searching over the internet for solutions, I still can't seem to fix this error. Initially my **hibernate.cgf.xml**, is in src/main/java/resources. I tried to move it around folders such as WEB-INF and META-INF but it still can't find the location.

Here's my **pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- Apache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="org.java.springsecudev.model.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springsecudev.dao" />

<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="configurationClass">
        <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>   

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>
</interceptors>

<beans:bean id="encoder"  
class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="12"></beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

> **EDIT:** Thanks to Balwinder I was able to recheck my file location. It was indeed supposed to be in src/main/resources turns out I was filing it in src/test/resources.

Comment: Check this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973381/classpath-problem-configlocation-in-spring

Comment: You should remove the new error and keep the original error here. The new error should be asked in a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your hibernate.cfg.xml to src/main/resources folder

Comment: It's currently in there : src/main/resources/hibernate.cgf.xml , that's why I'm wondering why I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Reiion Isn't it supposed to be `hibernate.cfg.xml` instead of `hibernate.cgf.xml`? Seems like wrong file name

Comment: I rechecked I was putting it in src/test/resources. Although now I'm getting another error on my sessionFactoryBean :

Comment: @Reiion Great a step forward. You can share the sessionFactoryBean error if you want to :)

Comment: @Reiion you should create a separate query for same, so that people can benefit from this type of error by looking here. Also, if this solved your error, simply accept the solution and create a new question with sessionFactoryBean error

Comment: Understood :)  Thanks again Balwinder